# VirtualBox Minix3 panic

Tags: cpu, virtualization, virtualbox, minix

Have googled, search reports, that such error could be if virtualization is disabled on PC. I've checked in BIOS config, it's enabled. My CPU is Core i3.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your hardware supports virtualization, make sure it's activated in the BIOS. Then make sure that "Enable VT-x/AMD-V" is checked in the tab of the VM settings.

If this solution is doesn't help for you, try to use this command to start the VM:

```
VBoxSDL --startvm "Minix 3" --norawr0 --norawr3
```

Comment: not using *nix, I'm using Windows 2012 (win8 core), have removed Vbox, but may say that I've used the latest version for the date I've started this question. So, what was the latest version of the Vbox 2 moths ago?